# Why isn't there a getCookie(String) method in the HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

As a software consultant, I have been using the Servlet API since the dawn of the man, but I always want to know, why there isn't a getCookie(String) method in the HttpServletRequest?

The API only defines the getCookies() method wich returns an array of Cookies, so if you are looking for some specific cookie at the Servlet level you have to iterate over the whole array, having a getCookie method would be great, don't you think?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question. The last sentence is needlessly provocative, perhaps, but it's probably a pretty common question and the answer could be educational.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty sure, no one here can provide a final answer to your question, but you should keep in mind that the *Servlet API* is a fairly low-level thing. It provides basic abstractions around the HTTP protocol, that's why the whole world uses libraries providing a higher degree of abstraction (spring, struts, jsf, lift, etc.).

BTW: The cookie name must not necessarily be unique, a cookie is identified by its name and path.